# How to update GridViewDataComboBoxColumn items from designer/Graphically in asp.net devexpress gridview

Tags: devexpress

I have added GridViewDataComboBoxColumn and list items to it in a gridview control and i want to update it when i click on edit and select items from the GridViewDataComboBoxColumn and click on update button that list items are not updating i am a designer and i don't know c# please give a solution to do it from designer/graphical.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" KeyFieldName="ID" EnableTheming="True" Theme="Office2010Blue">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowEditButton="True" VisibleIndex="0">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Click &quot;Edit&quot; button below for Update
                </HeaderTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="1">
                <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ProjectName" VisibleIndex="2" ReadOnly="True">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Menu" VisibleIndex="3" ReadOnly="True">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ErrorDescription" VisibleIndex="5">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="DeveloperRemarks" VisibleIndex="6" ReadOnly="True">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ReportedBy" VisibleIndex="7" ReadOnly="True">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FixedBy" VisibleIndex="8" ReadOnly="True">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="ErrorType" VisibleIndex="4">
                <PropertiesComboBox DropDownStyle="DropDownList">
               <Items>
                   <dx:ListEditItem Text="ScreenValidation" />
                   <dx:ListEditItem Text="Validation" />
                   <dx:ListEditItem Text="Syntax"  />
                   <dx:ListEditItem Text="Logical" />
                   <dx:ListEditItem Text="Layout" />
               </Items>
                    </PropertiesComboBox>
            </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="Status" VisibleIndex="9">
                <PropertiesComboBox DropDownStyle="DropDownList">
               <Items>
                   <dx:ListEditItem Text="Bug"/>
                   <dx:ListEditItem Text="Fixed"/>
                   <dx:ListEditItem Text="Closed" />
               </Items>
                    </PropertiesComboBox>
            </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
        </Columns>
        <SettingsDataSecurity AllowDelete="False" AllowInsert="False" />
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ErrorReportDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [BugsReport]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [BugsReport] SET [ProjectName] = @ProjectName, [Menu] = @Menu, [ErrorType] = @ErrorType, [ErrorDescription] = @ErrorDescription, [DeveloperRemarks] = @DeveloperRemarks, [ReportedBy] = @ReportedBy, [FixedBy] = @FixedBy, [Status] = @Status WHERE [ID] = @ID">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Menu" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ErrorType" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ErrorDescription" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DeveloperRemarks" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ReportedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FixedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" OnClick="ASPxButton1_Click" Text="Click Here To Insert New Record" Theme="Office2003Blue">
    </dx:ASPxButton>
```

Comment: It is not clear what the "update" means - does it mean update in either way the markup generated by the designer or your question is mostly related to the runtime behavior (maybe updating the data). Please better explain your requirements. And, I am afraid, ASPxGridView is mostly for developers, not for designers. It is unlikely that you can do everything you want without knowing C# or VB.NET.

Comment: Yes i want to Update My Data from  from ListEditItem

Answer (score 0):

To support updating data in the database, it is necessary to declare an appropriate UpdateCommand in the SqlDataSource. For example:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [BugsReport] SET [ErrorType] = @ErrorType WHERE ID = @ID
```

The complete explanation of SqlDataSource functions with examples is provided in this blog: [Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data with the SqlDataSource](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-vb).

When bound to the SqlDataSource component, the ASPxGridView can issue the UPDATE query automatically. To make this functionality work properly, it is necessary to specify the [KeyFieldName](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridBase_KeyFieldNametopic) property value. It should point to the identity column in the data source.